# Object is not iterable error in Django with view function

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django, and this is a test project.

This is the content of *views.py*:

```
def empleado(request, empleado_id):
    empleados = Empleado.objects.get(pk=empleado_id)
    context =  {
        'titulo':'Detalle de empleados',
        'lista_empleados': empleados
    }
    return render(request, 'empleados.html', context)
```

the model:

```
class Empleado(models.Model):
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    habilidades = models.ManyToManyField(Habilidad)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    antiguedad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for empleado in lista_empleados %}
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>empleado.id</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>empleado.nombre</td>
        <td>Antiguedad</td>
        <td>empleado.antiguedad</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

the table content:

[image]

I don't know why this is the `empleados` variable content, there is only one element:

```
<Empleado: nombre = Uno_de_prueba, fecha de nacimiento = 2020-06-01, antiguedad = 1>
```

An when I call the url I get this error:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'Empleado' object is not iterable
```

Am I not getting the table content in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `get` method it returns only one element (an `Empleado`) ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)). In the case there are not`Empleado` with the `pk` specified an exception will be raised.

If you want to get a list of `Empleado` you have to use `find`, `all` or any other method that return a `QuerySet`.

Maybe the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) could be useful to you for making queries in Django